# Can $\Phi_n(\Phi_n(n))$ be a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Can $$f(n):=\Phi_n(\Phi_n(n))$$ where $n$ is a positive integer, be a prime number , where $\Phi_n(x)$ denotes the $n-th$ cyclotomic polynomial ?

- If $n$ is a prime power $p^k$ ($p$ prime , $k$ positive integer), then we can show $p\mid f(n)$ , hence we cannot have a prime number.
- I checked upto $n=389$ without finding a prime number.
- Small factors are not forced : I know no prime factor of $f(45)$ (I invite everyone to search for one) , the smallest has very probably more than $30$ digits.
- I could not find forced algebraic or aurifeuillan factors.

Can we show that there is no prime of this form or do we just have to continue the search ?

Comment: The size of $f(n)$ is approximately $n^{\varphi(n)^2}$, which grows like $e^{n^{2 \pm \epsilon}}$.  Thus $\sum 1/\log f(n)$ converges.  This suggests that there may only be finitely many primes in the sequence, and quite possibly none (even if there's no "reason" there can't be any.)

Comment: (continued) This heuristic has the following limitation:  according to Bateman-Horn, values of $\Phi_n$ are more likely to be prime than the prime number theorem would predict, by a multiplicative factor that depends on $n$.  I don't think this multiplicative factor grows quickly enough as a function of $n$ to make the series above diverge, but someone should check this more carefully.

Comment: If $f(n)=p$ represents the prime $p$, we can form the polynomial $\Phi_n(\Phi_n(x))-p$. Since $n$ is not a power of a prime, the constant term is $1-p$. By the rational root theorem $n$ must divide $p-1$.

Comment: I tested all $ n < 789 $ with PFGW. No probable prime numbers in that range.